# Why does this "proof" fail to show rationals are uncountable?

Tags: solution-verification

I know that rationals are countable, but I'm not seeing the flaw in this reasoning showing that rationals are uncountable:

We start by defining $f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb Q$ such that
$$
1 \mapsto \frac{p_1}{q_1}\\
2 \mapsto \frac{p_2}{q_2}\\
3 \mapsto \frac{p_3}{q_3}\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
$$

Then, we construct a new rational number, $c$, such that

$$c=\frac{2^{p_1}5^{p_2}11^{p_3}...}{3^{q_1}7^{q_2}13^{q_3}...}$$

where we choose the bases of the exponents to be prime numbers, alternating between numerator and denominator. We know $c$ is in simplest form, and both the numerator and denominator are unique. Therefore, $c$ is not in our list which contradicts our assumption that we can construct an all-inclusive listing.

Obviously the conclusion is absurd, but why? Secondly, why can this reasoning be used to prove $\Bbb R$ is uncountable but can't be used to prove $\Bbb Q$ is uncountable?

Comment: $c$ does not appear to be a rational number.

Comment: It looks like the numerator/denominator of $c$ both have an infinite number of terms, so the conclusion that $c$ is rational is dubious. Moreover, even if it is rational, it's not obvious why $c$ wouldn't appear in the list of rationals used to construct it.

Comment: The product defining $c$ is probably not convergent. And if it is, it can be any real number. Including one of the rationals.

Comment: @Alex R. Thanks! Can't believe I missed that. And my reasoning for $c$ not being in the list is that the numerator and denominator are both greater than any numerator and denominator preceding it since it's being constructed using exponents of a positive integer base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, as mentioned in the comments the "object" $c$ you've described is rather problematic: it's not at all clear that that infinite product is well-defined (that is, that the appropriate limit actually exists and is finite).

More subtly, your argument that $c$ is not on the list breaks down since things aren't "stable" as we take the limit: it's a good exercise to show that there is a sequence of naturals $(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\prod_{i=1}^n{(p_{2i-1})^{a_{2i-1}}\over (p_{2i})^{a_{2i}}}={17\over 42}$$ (for example).

That said, this is in some sense superficial: we can replace the OP's construction with a "digit-by-digit" construction, a la Cantor's diagonal argument, and produce a totally well-defined real number guaranteed to not be on the starting list. So why doesn't *that* show that the rationals are uncountable?

Well, the point is that there are actually **two** things we have to show about the "antidiagonal" object $\alpha$ we've constructed from a list $L$ in order to move forward with the diagonal argument:

- We must show that $\alpha$ is not in fact in $L$.
- We *also* must show that $\alpha$ is the "right sort of thing:" if the goal is to show that $L$ does not exhaust some set $S$, we have to argue that $\alpha\in S$.

When we're looking at the usual diagonal argument, this second step is basically trivial: any infinite string of digits is the expansion of a real number in $[0,1]$.

- More precisely, and in base $2$ for convenience: for any infinite binary sequence $(c_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$, the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n2^{-i}c_i$ exists and is in $[0,1]$.

For this reason it's often unstated. However, in general this may not be obvious, or indeed may be false. The OP is a case of the latter: when we apply the diagonal argument to a list of rationals, we get a real number (so far so good) which is not rational (oops).